# The objects give left by itself

Tags: php, html, css

The objects(a href) give left by itself :

https://mobile.donanimhaber.com/cache/ImageThumbnail2.aspx?path=https://store.donanimhaber.com/7e/6e/f7/7e6ef7b7b753da8d517d33ee273e247a.png

I writed this :

```
<div id="basliklar">

            <?php

            $baglanti = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kodlarinefendisi","php","");
            $baslikcek = $baglanti -> prepare("select * from konu");
            $baslikcek -> execute();

            $i = 0;

            foreach($baslikcek as $baslikgoster){

            $i++;

            $baslik = $baslikgoster["baslik"];

            $hrefbaslik = "kodlarinefendisi.com/".$baslikgoster["baslik"];

            $idbaslik = "baslik".$i;

            $basliktop = $i * 20;

            ?>

            <a onclick="return dhExternalLinkRedirect(this)" href="/ExternalLinkRedirect?url=<?php echo($hrefbaslik); ?>" id="<?php echo($idbaslik); ?>" data-href="<?php echo($hrefbaslik); ?>" id="<?php echo($idbaslik); ?>" ><?php echo($baslik); ?></a>

            <style>

            <?php

            echo "#baslik".$i."{";
            echo "position: relative;";
            echo "top:".$basliktop."px;";
            echo "left: 0px;";
            echo "}";

            ?>

            </style>

            <?php

            }

            ?>

            </div>

<style type="text/css">

    #basliklar{

        position: relative;
        top: -10px;
        left: 350px;

    }

</style>
```

You see i don't give left to a tags.

How can i resolve this problem?

I need your help.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the elements with the F12 developer tools and seeing where the styling is coming from?

Comment: @ObsidianAge yes i tired but i don't seeing